# JavaScript/JQuery - How do I get img Height once new img src is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a custom carousel I'm working on, below is some parts of the code... It's huge so I won't bother with putting a full working example.

Anyway I passed a JSON object from php containing the file name of the images.  When the right arrow is clicked, the element,

```
<img id="carousel_image" src="http://example.org/image/image.jpg" />
```

changes to a new src using jQuery,

```
$('#arrow_right').click(function(){
        $('#carousel_image').attr('src', storedSlides[currentSlide]);
        $('#carousel_image').ready(function(){
           console.log($('#carousel_image').height()); //returns 1000
        });
        console.log($('#carousel_image').height()); //returns 1000
    });
```

Both logs return 1000, the height of the original image prior to the click.  How can I get the true height of the new image (once fully loaded)?

Thank you kindly for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `load` event, not `ready`, ready is fired when the `DOM` is rendered. `load` is fired when the image is loaded on `img` elements.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp

```
$('#arrow_right').click(function(){
    $('#carousel_image').attr('src', storedSlides[currentSlide]);
    $('#carousel_image').on("load", function(){
       console.log($('#carousel_image').height());
    });
    console.log($('#carousel_image').height());
});
```

Comment: You have not only taught me something new, but solved my problem (and brought me to my next problem)! ahaha